# Do bonuses stack if they come from 2 identical magic items that don't require attunement?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, stacking

Do bonuses stack if they come from 2 identical magic items that **don't require attunement**? In particular using 2 transmuter stones with 2 different effects.What if both stones give 10 speed?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, the bonuses will not stack. Though it is not present in original printings, [errata to the Dungeon Master's Guide](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/DMG-Errata.pdf) (and later reprintings of the book) add a section on page 252, **Combining Game Effects**:

> Different game features can affect a target at the same time. But when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one apply while the durations of the effects overlap. For example, if a target is ignited by a fire elemental’s Fire Form trait, the ongoing fire damage doesn’t increase if the burning target is subjected to that trait again. Game features include spells, class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic items. See the related rule in the “Combining Magical Effects” section of chapter 10 in the Player’s Handbook.

Comment: I knew this rule was there somewhere! What makes this a bit different/confusing  is that the two stones can have completely different effects, even though they are the same feature.

Comment: That section of the DMG is actually errata, so it's not present in earlier prints of the book - I have a copy where it is not present at all. You should probably reference the published errata, or possibly the intro to XGtE, where the rule is effectively restated.

Comment: @J.E this case is unfortunately somewhat ambiguous - XGtE states "But when two or more effects have the same proper name, only one of them (the most powerful one if their benefits aren’t identical)...". I could see this leading to arguments about which particular version of the transmuter's stone offers "the most powerful effect".

Comment: @Carcer yeah, and the wording in XGtE is making it worse by takling about *effects'* proper names, not items or features. Would that mean that the four different effects of the stones are each unique in this sense? (...I don't think so)

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me from the XGtE version's "it their effects aren't identical" clause. If  you have a spell that allows you to apply ongoing damage of a type of your choice (chosen at casting), and you cast it two times on the same creature and choose two different damage types, they stack since the effects are not identical, even though the spell's (or effect's) proper name is. Likewise with the magic item here - same proper name, but two different benefits  = they stack.

Comment: The distinction gets muddied if the spell grants multiple effects and only some overlap with a different casting. We know that identical bonuses (such as to AC) stack if they come from different sources, and that different effects from the same source stack (as I mention above), but what if a spell provides say "+1 to AC and resistance to an element of your choice". If you cast it twice on the same target and choose two different elements, does the AC bonus stack? I'd say no, of course, but that isn't exactly clear from the rules (and such abilities may not exist in the official materials).

Comment: @cpcodes In context, I don't think that the rule means what you're claiming. The full statement is: "But when two or more effects have the same proper name, only one of them (the most powerful one if their benefits aren’t identical), applies while the durations of the effects overlap." The "aren't identical" part is only used to determine which of the two benefits apply: it isn't a criteria for them not stacking. The only criteria for that is "two or more effects have the same proper name."

Comment: @Carcer It can be difficult to decide which effect is the most powerful. Jeremy Crawford has suggested that if the two spells are equally potent but have different effects (E.G. two uses of the Command spell with different orders), [you should use the most recently applied spell.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/774030127529201664?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sageadvice.eu%2F2016%2F10%2F07%2Ftwo-successful-command-spells-on-the-same-target-what-happens-next-round%2F) The rules are probably similar for other effects.

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme Now that I reread it after your explanation, I see now that here benefits is most commonly referring to the magnitude of the effect - i.e. that +1 to armor and +2 to armor are different benefits, and the +2 would be the winner (assuming both from a source with the same name). In this case, yes, picking two different elements for the resistance spell would only result in the higher level spell taking effect, or as per the Crawford quote you provided, the most recently cast if they are equal. I'll leave my previous comments for completeness, but I now realize that they are wrong.